# how to change permissions of specific file type

Tags: bash, chmod, shell-scripting

```
 file * |  grep 'ASCII text' | chmod -x 
chmod: missing operand
Try `chmod --help' for more information.
```

The above command gives me error.Basically I am trying to find all the files whose type is ASCII and change their permissions to -x.What mistake is there in above syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**One:** `grep 'ASCII text'` returns **not only** the file name, but also the type of the file itself; you need to process the output to return *only* the file name

**Two:** `chmod` does not accept arguments from STDIN, which is what you're trying to do with the pipe `|`. You'll have to either use `xargs` or wrap the above in a `for` loop

That said, here are two solutions for you:

**Solution #1: With Pipes**

```
file * | awk '/ASCII text/ {gsub(/:/,"",$1); print $1}' | xargs chmod -x
```

**Solution #2: With for-loop**

```
for fn in $(file * | awk '/ASCII text/ {gsub(/:/,"",$1); print $1}'); do chmod -x "$fn"; done
```

Pick yer poison :-)

Answer (score 2):

This should work regardless of whether filenames contain spaces or colons:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sh -c 'file -b "{}" | grep -sq ASCII' \; -print0 | xargs -0 chmod -x
```

You can remove the `-maxdepth 1` to make it recursive.

There may be false positives if filenames themselves contain the string "ASCII".

**Edit:**

I incorporated pepoluan's suggestion of using the `-b` option for `file` so the filename isn't output for the test by `grep`. This should eliminate false positives.

Comment: Then the grep should match with [[:space:]]ASCII ... for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448997/egrep-search-for-whitespace

Comment: @pepoluan: If you're talking about the part where I mention potential false positives, then it is correct that the more specific the regex is the less chance there is, but a filename could still match `[[:space:]]ASCII`.

Comment: @Dennis: Ah, you're right. In that case, I suggest using `awk -F ":" '/ASCII/ && $1!~/ASCII/ {print $1}`

Comment: @pepoluan: But what if a file with "ASCII" in its name is an ASCII file? You don't want to falsely reject a file, either. Or if there's a file named "ASCII:ASCII" ... ad infinitum. You can reduce the chances, but you can't eliminate them.

Comment: Heh, possible. Maybe better to have `for fn in *; do [[ $(file -b "$fn") =~ ASCII ]] && chmod -x "$fn"; done`. What do you think?

Comment: @pepoluan: That's a good idea. It can be incorporated into my version which doesn't use an explicit loop.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson great answer.I observed you have given good answers to all my questions.Hope to get more support from you in near future also :)

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in `file * | grep "ASCII text" | awk "{print \\$1}" | awk -F ":" "{print \\$1}"`; do chmod -x "$f"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

And another one liner - be aware of the need to strip the `:    ASCII Text` and quote the names too

```
file * | grep 'ASCII text' | sed  's|\(^.*\):.*|\"\1\"|'| xargs chmod -x
```